# How do i specify the location of network interface created by packer while using an existing resource group to build a windows image in azure

Tags: windows, azure, image, packer, nic

packer i used

```
`{
    "builders": [
      {
        "name": "image",
        "type": "azure-arm",

        "os_disk_size_gb": "256",
        "vm_size": "Standard_F8s_v2",
        "managed_image_storage_account_type": "Standard_LRS",
        
        "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "tenant_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "subscription_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "object_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

        "managed_image_name": "mypackerimage",
        "managed_image_resource_group_name": "resource_group_name",
        "build_resource_group_name": "rg",

        "virtual_network_name": "VizDev-AzureDevOps-vnet",
        "virtual_network_resource_group_name": "VizDev-AzureDevOps",
        "virtual_network_subnet_name": "default",

        "os_type": "Windows",
        "image_publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
        "image_offer": "WindowsServer",
        "image_sku": "2022-Datacenter",
        "communicator": "winrm",
        "winrm_use_ssl": "true",
        "winrm_insecure": "true",
        "winrm_username": "packer"

      }
    ],
    "provisioners": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "script": "./provisioning-script.sh"
      },
      {
        "type": "powershell",
        "inline": [
          "Write-Output 'Hello, Packer!'"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }`
```

please find the error code as below :

` Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:

```
--> azure-arm.image: polling after CreateOrUpdate: Code="DeploymentFailed" Message="At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details." Targ
et="/subscriptions//resourceGroups/VizDev-AzureDevOps/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/pkrdpgt4raapkqo" Details=[{"code":"InvalidResourceReference","details":[],"message":"Resource /subscriptions/resourceGroups/VizDev-AzureDevOps/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/VizDev-AzureDevOps-vnet/subnets/default referenced by resource /subscriptions//resourceGroups/VizDev-AzureDevOps/providers/M
icrosoft.Network/networkInterfaces/pkrnigt4raapkqo was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same region."}]
```

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.`

Comment: To specify the location of the network interface created by Packer, you need to ensure that the network interface is created within the same region and resource group where Packer is building the image.

Comment: how do i ensure that can i specify this in the packer build template if yes can you share a reference to it @VenkatV

Comment: Create a NIC in the same resource group and region. Once the NIC is created, copy its resource ID and add it to the 'network_interface_id' field in your Packer code.

Comment: I don't think there is a configuration key to add this value if there is one please let me know. when i added this 1 error occurred:
 * unknown configuration key: '"network_interface_id"'
 @VenkatV

Answer (score 0):

By default, packer should use the resource group location, so check if `"virtual_network_resource_group_name": "VizDev-AzureDevOps"` and `"build_resource_group_name": "rg"` exist in the same location. Both RGs should exist in the same subscription (`"subscription_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`). `location` can be used when `build_resource_group_name` is not defined.

> Providing temp_resource_group_name or location in combination with build_resource_group_name is not allowed.

As a starting point you can use basic example provided in documentation:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/integrations/hashicorp/azure/latest/components/builder/arm#basic-example